# ASP.NET MVC - Firefox still keep selected value of dropdownlist after pressing F5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, drop-down-menu

I put an dropdownlist inside an ajax form, when change SelectedIndex the form will load new html. Then I press F5, the dropdownlist still keep the SelectedIndex even though the SelectedIndex in the returned html is 0.

This only happened on Firefox (I ran on FF 15.0.1)
Is there any trick to resolve this?

Comment: Could you reproduce the problem at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Can you delete the Firefox cache & try F5 ? It may be possible that page is served from browser cache.

Comment: Just try using Crt+F5; it will remove the cache and reload the page

Comment: you can add js script that will reset value in CB after loading. In you script you need pay atantion on method, so if 'post' - you shoud reset, if not - not

Comment: the same in Comodo browser